# nested ng-controller fires $locationChangeStart?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-controller

I have some parent Ctrl which has `locationChangeStart` function implememted. Also I have Child controller which binds data from html to parent controller

html:

```
 <div> <!-- parent ctrl setted in routing -->
   <div  ng-controller="ChildCtrl as childCtrl" 
         ng-init="childCtrl.setObjectName('somename')">
     <textarea name="name" ng-model="parentObject.name"></textarea>
   </div> <!-- end of child -->
</div> <!-- end of parent-->
```

parent ctrl:

```
app.controller('ParentCtrl', function ($scope,$stateParams,config){
    console.log("in parent");
    $scope.timerPromise = null;
    $scope.parentObject= {};


$scope.timerPromise = $interval(
    function(){

    },config.AUTOSAVE_TIMER_FREQUENCY);

console.log($scope.timerPromise);



$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event) {
    if($scope.timerPromise) {
        $interval.cancel($scope.timerPromise);
    }
    console.log("route changed in parent");
});
```

child Ctrl

```
app.controller('ChildCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams) {
    console.log('in child');

    var vm = this;

    vm.objectId = $stateParams.id;


    vm.setObjectName = function(objectName) {
        console.log('setting object name in commets+'+objectName);
        vm.objectName = objectName;

    };
  });
```

My problem is the following - binding from/to parent ctrl variables is OK, i see data from server in child ctrl via ng-model but autosave in parent not working because **locationChangeStart fires after loading parent ctrl** even if I don't press back button and even didn't press anything. Location change event stops timer. **Why locationChangeStart fired even if I didn't press anything?** Is it because of nested controller? May I use non-aliased,not ng-controller tagged, setted in routing parent controller and aliased child controller together?

My console outputs is the folowing:

```
in parent
Promise {$$state: Object, $$intervalId: 160} // timer promise
in child
setting object name in commets+somename
route changed in parent
```

You see, route changed and my question is about that strange behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28600938/2104560 - `locationChangeStart` came from old ngRoute now I'm using ui-router and have to use `stateChangeStart` event.